# Jinja2 and Json

Tags: python, json, jinja2

I have for example a JSON File

```
{
    "Google":{
    "Web":"www.web.de",
    "Apps":{
        "Drive": "DriveLink",
        "Dropbox": "DropboxLink"
    },
    "Google Main":"http://mail.google.com",
    "G+":"http://plus.google.com"
    },  
    "Social":{
    "Facebook":"http://www.facebook.de",
    "G+":"https://plus.google.com",
    "Xing":"http://www.xing.de",
    "LinkedIn":"http://www.linkedin.com",
    "Tumblr":"http://www.tumblr.com"
    },
    "Fun":{
    "Reddit":"http://www.reddit.com"
    }
}
```

As you can see I have under the section Google a Nested Section named Apps

With CherryPy I hand over this JSON Object as following with the name linksList:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def index(self):
    linksFile = open('links.json', 'r')
    linksList = json.load(linksFile) 

    template = jinjaEnv.get_template('index.html')
    return template.render(linksList=linksList)
```

What I want is to render following:

1. Google

   - Web (as a link)
   - Google Main
   - G+
   - Apps

     - Drive
     - Dropbox
2. Social

   - Facebook
   - G+
   - Xing

and so on

What I don't understand is to do is to render this nested Objects like "Apps" recursively

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates) reads:

> It is possible to use loops recursively. This is useful if you are
>   dealing with recursive data such as sitemaps. To use loops recursively
>   you basically have to add the recursive modifier to the loop
>   definition and call the loop variable with the new iterable where you
>   want to recurse.

In your case this would be accomplished with the following:

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in linksList.items() recursive %}
    <li>
    {% if value is string %}
        <a href="{{ value }}">{{ key }}</a>
    {% else %}
        {{ key }}
        <ul>{{ loop(value.items()) }}</ul>
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Ryon, thank you very much. That was exactly what I was searching for. What exactly helped was to test for a string. I tried for a dict a got an TemplateAssertionError: no test named 'dict'. Why is it that you cannot test for a dict or a list

Comment: @lennykey It looks like Jinja doesn't provide a [built-in test](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-tests) for dict or list though it is possible to [create your own](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-tests).

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents, just if someone comes here looking for *rendering a JSON using Jinja*, and complementing the response from @Ryon Sherman :)

1. Since JSON may have int values as well as strings, you can use `if value is mapping` (and flip the if-condition)
2. If your output must feel like a JSON you can use `{{key|indent(width)}}` + `loop.depth`
3. In my case, the template was for an email and `key|indent()` didn't work as expected so I ended up using an auxiliar `{% for %}` loop:

```
<div>
    <code>{
    {% for key, value in dic.items() recursive %}
    {% if value is mapping %}
    <p>
     {% for it in range(loop.depth) %}&nbsp;&nbsp;{% endfor %}{{key}}: {
    </p>
    {{ loop(value.items()) }}
    <p>
      {% for it in range(loop.depth) %}&nbsp;&nbsp;{% endfor %}}
    </p>
    {% else %}
    <p>
      {% for it in range(loop.depth) %}&nbsp;&nbsp;{% endfor %}{{key}}: {{value}},
    </p>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    }</code>
</div>
```